# Which else Tex editors for windows are such that XeCJK is smoothly workable?

Tags: xetex, editors, xecjk

I already know there are Tex editors compatible
with XeLaTeX, say Texstudio and Texworks, so that they can process the XeCJK package. But I find
that these two editors somehow get slow when 
using XeLaTeX along with the XeCJK package. I thus wonder
if there is any other Tex editor such that 
it can go smoothly with XeCJK and therefore XeLaTeX ?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{cwTeX Q Yuan Medium}
\begin{document}
妳好.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel like emacs/vim would be good here.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard of Vim but never tried it before.  Is it workable in Windows?

Comment: I don't use vim much, but I would be appalled if it didn't. I know emacs does work on windows.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question closely. This isn't a problem with the editor, but an issue with XeTeX.  Something is likely slowing XeTeX down (maybe weird font selection or something like that).  The editor only *edits* your document – XeTeX is the engine that *produces* the PDF from your source file. See [Who's Who in the World of TeX](http://www.seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html) for more information about this distinction. I would add a minimal working example that shows the slowdown – maybe there's something that can be done about it. It's not the editor's fault ;-)

Comment: …I'm looking forward to it, too – it's your move :) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Haha, yes, hold on.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Please be referred to the edited question.

Comment: I don't have the font specified, but I replaced it with `Songti SC` and I'm not seeing a slowdown. If the font is free, can you provide a link for download? Otherwise, I'm not sure how much further I can help.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for that! I found that the choice of font does not affect the speed. But I found that, in TexStudio, if xeCJK is not deployed then the output can be shown withtin 3 seconds. But if xeCJK is deployed then the output is shown after at least 7 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24826/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-chou).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Sorry. Somehow I am not in a position to do anything in the chat room?